# How to display all event-titles for a day in basic week of fullcalendar without '+more text'

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar to display event-titles for my project in basic-week view.

My client wants all events to be displayed for a day with scroll. I have huge amount of data for a day which full-calendar rearranges as 50+ more text. I don't want to display this 50+ more text - I want all events to be displayed on single screen and not on a pop up screen.

Moreover, I am using mobile devices to display calendar there. Popup looks more odd.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`eventLimit`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/) option. If you set this option to `false`, all events will be listed.

In [this jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/120eLr7j/1/) I've taken the demo of http://fullcalendar.io/ and switched `eventLimit: false` and all events are displayed.